# How to spoof IP address in Spring to preserve client IP address when calling other API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, tomcat, ip-address

I need to call an external API with my Spring back-end where it preserves the client's IP address. Essentially, the external API generates a token based on the IP address of the client, and that token won't work unless the IP of the recipient matches the IP of the requestor. Thus, if I make a request with my back-end, the IP will be that of the server, not the client, and the token won't work.

I've already tried the HTTP headers `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Real-IP`, and `Host`, but none of them are accepted by the external API. I need to actually spoof the IP address of the server to match that of the client.

How does one do this?

Comment: Not sure ip spoofing would work for you. If you don't need a response it could work but if you do need the response it will be sent to the address you are impersonating. You'd need to be on the same subnet or control the network to get it. [IP spoofing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55279/how-easy-is-it-really-to-do-ip-spoofing) is generally considered hacking and the server you are calling most likely doesn't want you to do this.

Comment: did u find any answer to do it with spring boot?

Comment: @SeyedAliRoshan No, I ended up doing a CORS proxy implementation. It was less than ideal, but worked enough for me to call it done. I'd still be very welcome to any suggestions others have, even if it means the response is returned directly to the IP I'm impersonating (in fact, that would be ideal).